# How to send files via apache camel directly to git remote repo?

Tags: java, git, apache-camel

I am quite new in Camel and I'm facing an issue while sending a file to git repository nothing happens. I know it is a bit inconvenient but I really need this particular feature to be in my project. I've read the documentation and came out with something like this.

```
private void FtGRoute(){
from(InputPath)
        .routeId("ToGit")
        .setHeader(GitConstants.GIT_FILE_NAME, constant("CamelToGit.xml"))
        .to("git://C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/projectName?operation=add")
        .setHeader(GitConstants.GIT_COMMIT_MESSAGE, constant("file to git commit"))
        .to("git://C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/projectName?operation=commit")
        .to("git://C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/projectName?operation=push&remotePath=https://github.com/name/CamelToGit.git");
```

I'll be more than happy if somebody will help me with this.

Comment: What is the issue or error?

Comment: There is no error sent back. It compiles but nothing happens. That's the issue.

Comment: @Tushar I forgot to call you up